# How to save firebase notification on android device?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase Push Notifications in my kotlin code successfully. Now, How can I save those on the device, and access them in a new activity?
I searched the internet but I cannot find any code/example of something like that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save those notifications and that show them in your app at a later stage
try storing them in a local db on arrival and then fetch them where needed.
this should guide you: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room